# Are caches saved per locale by default?

Tags: localization, cache

Or do we need to set a specific key that includes something unique?

Comment: Take a look at the `craft_templatecaches` table in your database, specifically the `locale` column. You'll notice that every instance of caching is automatically associated with its respective locale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're referring to template caches with the [{% cache %}](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/cache) tag.

If so, then yes, the `{% cache %}` tag by default will cache it's contents on a per URL and per locale basis.

If you use the [globally](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/cache#globally) parameter, then it will just be on a per locale basis.